# Realm Giving Wrong result count on distinct

Tags: android, database, realm

I have i weird problem in realm result. when i distinct the result in realmquery it's giving me 3826 count

[image]

but when i findall item with same query it's giving me only 611. the correct one is 611. i didn't understand why realm showing me 3826 count when there is only 611 distinct records in database 
[image]

Comment: We will need to see how you structure this model. Is `NROPEDIDO` column a foreign key? And please provide your queries as text for better reading

Comment: I think this is a bug introduced with the new `.distinct` on `RealmQuery` so I opened an issue for it. You can use `.distinct().findAll().size()` though for now

Comment: Hi @Gurtek. I cannot reproduce the results you get here. Can you provide more information about your data model? This issue is tracking it: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5958

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce i already do that to find count but want to know the reason why this count giving me wrong result

Comment: @Gurtek can you provide more information in the issue I linked so we can investigate this properly.